# jQuery slideUp() and slideDown() with Rounded Corners

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let's cut to the chase, here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B7Uyj/1/

Here's my current jQuery functions that handle the slideUp() and slideDown() features:

```
var mostRecent = "";
var timeoutID = null;
$(".notif_button").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    mostRecent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('300');
    $("#hide_notification").slideDown('slow');
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#hide_notification").slideUp('slow');
    }, 10000);
});

$("#undo_notif").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#" + mostRecent).fadeIn('300');
    $("#hide_notification").slideUp('slow');
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
});
```

I did not upload the "x" image I am using, but if you click in the areas where the image is missing (at the top right of the small notification windows), you can see how this functions.

The issue I'm having is that when I use the slideUp() and slideDown() functions, you can see the rounded corners of the div that's moving and it doesn't look like the "undo notification" truly emerged from the bottom of its parent container. This isn't an error; that's exactly how it *should* work. My question is, is there a way to make it look as though the yellow div that pops up is NOT separated from its parent? This is hard to explain, so please ask if you need clarification. My guess is to dynamically change the border radius as the slideUp() or slideDown() action happens.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: +1 for fiddle and formatted code :)

Comment: and your explanation is clear of what you are looking for +1 too

Comment: Thank you! Still new to StackOverflow but it's been a great help so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `overflow:hidden;` to container seems to fix it:

http://jsfiddle.net/B7Uyj/5/

Comment: Wow! I had no idea the fix was that simple! Thank you so much. I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.